# Media Player(Video + audio) In Blackberry(smartphones) - Java

Tags: blackberry, media-player

I have developing a streaming application where user can watch & listen audio & video(HD). The video in **flv,mp4,3gp** in any format that they watch.

**Issue:**

The problem that i facing, in BB there is no built in player that support these video formates. Is there any Media Player(free) that support these formates or develop custom streaming media player for it.
If there need to develop custom media player, how can i start(sample).
Please provide some assistance, any sample code/link/idea etc.

Answer (score 1):

mp4 and 3gp formats are [supported by RIM OS](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18577/Supported_audio_video_file_formats_60_1018040_11.jsp).  And here is [the sample code, that shows how to play video](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Create_BB_app_that_plays_a_video_in_a_UI_field_739692_11.jsp).